# Cleaning Excel Table using VBA without impacting the entire table and formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to change to write VBA for excel to clean up data elements that has extra information without impacting the other elements.

I am writing VBA for the first time my table is in the middle of the sheet.

Given Table and Requested Output.

[image: Given Table and Requested Output.]

Comment: *I am writing VBA* And where's your VBA? 

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The question is that I want to format the table according to column valueC however first there are some extra string that need to be cleaned up first and then i have to separate the ids in one row to multiple rows  also need to add the other elements as it is in the blank fields so that reference wont impact to customer ID--I am currently looking up some videos for table referencing so that I can write on my own but still I need help it seems.

Comment: That's not a question, but a list of requirements. S.O. is not a free code writing service. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53916738/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was not clear in regard to the "steps" that you want to perform on your data (i.e. the exact logic or transformation that needs to be applied).

Based purely on your images and your comment, I make the "steps" to be:

1. Split any customer IDs in column `valueC` into multiple rows.
2. If column `valueC` does not contain customer IDs (i.e. is blank or contains non-customer ID text), leave it untouched.

My answer uses Power Query instead of VBA. If you are interested in trying it out, in Excel try clicking `Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query`, then click `Advanced Editor` near the top-left, copy-paste the code below, then click `Done`.

You might need to change the name of the table in the first line of the code (below), as it was `"Table1"` for me, but I imagine yours is named something else. Also, the code below is case-sensitive. So if there is no column named exactly `valueC`, then you will get an error.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    fxProcessSomeText = (textToProcess as any) =>
        let
            canBeSplit = Text.StartsWith(textToProcess, "### customer id"),
            result = if textToProcess is null then null else if canBeSplit then Text.Split(Text.BetweenDelimiters(textToProcess, "### customer id", " ###"), ",") else {textToProcess}
        in
            result,
    invokeFunction = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"valueC", fxProcessSomeText}}),
    expanded = Table.ExpandListColumn(invokeFunction, "valueC"),
    reindex =
        let
            removeIndex = Table.RemoveColumns(expanded, {"index"}),
            addIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(removeIndex, "index", 1, 1),
            moveIndex = Table.ReorderColumns(addIndex, List.Distinct(List.InsertRange(Table.ColumnNames(addIndex), 0, {"index"})))
        in
            moveIndex
in
    reindex
```

My output table contains more rows than yours. Also, the value in column `valueA`, row 11 is `1415` for me (it is `1234` in your request output). Not sure if this is a mistake in your example, or if I'm missing some logic.